# What does "[0]" do after ".filter()[0]" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, filter, syntax

I saw a function like this:

```
  getDish(id: number): Dish {
    return DISHES.filter((dish) => (dish.id === id))[0];
  }
```

But I can't understand why does it use `[0]` after filter function? I mean what the return value of `filter` looks like and why does it specifies the index `0` only?

EDIT: This is `DISHES`:

```
export const DISHES: Dish[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label: 'Hot',
        price: '4.99',
        featured: true,
        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author: "John Lemon",
                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                author: "Paul McVites",
                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                author: "Ringo Starry",
                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                author: "25 Cent",
                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Zucchipakoda',
        image: '/assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label: '',
        price: '1.99',
        featured: false,
        description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author: "John Lemon",
                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                author: "Paul McVites",
                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                author: "Ringo Starry",
                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                author: "25 Cent",
                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Vadonut',
        image: '/assets/images/vadonut.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label: 'New',
        price: '1.99',
        featured: false,
        description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author: "John Lemon",
                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                author: "Paul McVites",
                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                author: "Ringo Starry",
                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                author: "25 Cent",
                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: '/assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        label: '',
        price: '2.99',
        featured: false,
        description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
        comments: [
            {
                rating: 5,
                comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author: "John Lemon",
                date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                author: "Paul McVites",
                date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 3,
                comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 4,
                comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                author: "Ringo Starry",
                date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating: 2,
                comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                author: "25 Cent",
                date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Did you read `.filter` documentation, do you know what filter returns?

Comment: What does [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) do? Returns an array? What does `var x = [1,2,3]; y = x[0]` do when working with an array?

Comment: Code should be using find() and not filter()

Answer (score 2):

`filter` returns a filtered array. `[0]` accesses the first element of that array.

Comment: What is the returned value of filter looks like?

Comment: It is an array of all the dishes with a given ID.

Comment: filter filters an array and returns an array of the objects that returned true for a condition. [0] accesses the first index in the array. This is bad practice as its possible the array will be empty.

Comment: So why it only specifies the 0 index?

Comment: because whovever wrote the code assumes all id's are only used once so it will only ever be an array of 1 object

Comment: Its bad practice to assume everyone using your code will use it properly. Should check for length before accessing the first index because if the id does not exist it will throw a object undefined error.

Comment: @DerekLawrence No error will be thrown in the event no matching items are found. That said the code should probably use `Array#find` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @DerekLawrence _"...it will throw a object undefined error"_ - Why should `undefined` be an error? And there's nothing "thrown".